# Form not popping up upon running

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, office-interop

Here I have my vb6 code that plays around with an excel file. (I took this code off some other website.) This code compiles and builds but when I hit f5 it does the form does not po up. If I remove all the code in the Class then it pops up.

How would I fix this?
Sorry I am new at vb6, but not coding in general.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlwbook As Excel.Workbook

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'the benifit of placing numbers in (row, col) is that you
        'can loop through different directions if required. I could
        'have used column names like "A1" 'etc. 

        'Text1.Text = xlsheet.Cells(2, 1) ' row 2 col 1
        'Text2.Text = xlsheet.Cells(2, 2) ' row 2 col 2 

        'don't forget to do this or you'll not be able to open
        'book1.xls again, untill you restart you pc.
        xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False, "f:\a.xls")
        xl.Quit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load()
        xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Open("f:\a.xls")
        xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets.Item(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
        xlwbook = Nothing
        xl = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        xlsheet.Cells(2, 1) = "adsfasdfasdf"
        xlsheet.Cells(2, 2) = "qwerqwer"
        xlwbook.Save()

        'don't forget to do this or you'll not be able to open
        'book1.xls again, untill you restart you pc.
        xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False, "f:\a.xls")
        xl.Quit()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I suspect the opening of the excel file fails. Instead of having the form do all the heavy lifting for you, it's probably better to open the excel file instance before showing the form. That way you can do some error handling. Then pass the Excel workbook instance to the form after it has been opened.

Comment: I've retagged your question to VB.NET because this code is VB.NET and not VB6.

Comment: My guess is that Excel prevents `Workbooks.Open` from returning, e.g. by displaying a question which you might not see. Try `xl.Visible = True` in `Form_Load`.

Comment: Setting xl.Visible = True did not work. Trying to implement jessehowing's suggestion. Thanks guys.

Comment: @user2100799 Did you put it before anything else? If you did, then remove `New` from `Dim xl As New Excel.Application` and try creating a `New Excel.Application` from a button click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then it means that you are not adding reference to your project

follow the link to code and further details..

http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_2007_open_file.htm

Comment: The code from that site however works only if I replace ApplicationClass with Application. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

check file name, path and extension carefully.

```
     ("f:\a.xls")
```

extension may be xlsx.

Also check the name of sheet 1.

Comment: No  its not that. I made sure (I have both xls and xlsx just in case)